# Question about Tutorial : Introduction to Stage Controllers - stageros problem

Tags: ros, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI i'm ROS newbie.
I just follow the tutorial about Introduction to Stage Controllers : [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/stage/Tutorials/IntroductiontoStageControllers)

I achieved first two commands : "rosmake stage_controllers" and "rospack find stage_controllers"

But I have a problem at the next step.
I typed "rosrun stage stageros `rospack find stage_controllers`/world/roomba-wander.world" into the terminal
and the terminal show me "[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named stageros below /opt/ros/hydro/share/stage"

Of course I started with roscore.

I don't get why.
plz somebody help me....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200779/question-about-tutorial-:-introduction-to-stage-controllers---stageros-problem/) by [Akali](https://answers.ros.org/users/21316/akali/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2015-01-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the wiki might be outdated... If you're using hydro or indigo, you need to run:

```
$ rosrun stage_ros stageros `rospack find stage_controllers`/world/rooma-wander.world
```

I am not entirely familiar with the use of stage_controllers, but I think the syntax should be fine. Also, if you want an example of a roslaunch file, here is an [example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/allenh1/p2os/master/p2os_launch/launch/stage-pioneer-3dx-hokuyo.launch) for the p2os stack.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2015-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2018-03-26**:
Update roslaunch files to `<node pkg="stage_ros" type="stageros"` . Related:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/192600/stage-not-working/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/214157/how-do-i-install-stage-and-stage_ros/